# How to track the color in a movie frame

Tags: java, processing

I am working on a project that finds the average color of each scene from a movie and if those colors are within a certain threshold value of red then the frame will be saved as a png. The atnm1.mov reads that RuntimeException: Could not load movie file antm1.mov, and the files do not save?

```java
import processing.video.*;
color trackColor; 
float threshold;
Movie video;

void setup() {
  size(1200,900);
  video = new Movie(this, "antm1.mov");
  video.loop();
  trackColor = color(255, 0, 0);
}

void movieEvent(Movie video) {
  video.read();
}

void draw() {
  video.loadPixels();
  image(video, 0, 0);

  threshold = 80;
  float avgX = 0;
  float avgY = 0;
  int count = 0;

  // Begin loop to walk through every pixel
  for (int x = 0; x < video.width; x++ ) {
    for (int y = 0; y < video.height; y++ ) {
      int loc = x + y * video.width;
      // What is current color
      color currentColor = video.pixels[loc];
      float r1 = red(currentColor);
      float g1 = green(currentColor);
      float b1 = blue(currentColor);
      float r2 = red(trackColor);
      float g2 = green(trackColor);
      float b2 = blue(trackColor);

      float d = dist(r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2); 

      if (d < threshold*threshold) {
        avgX += x;
        avgY += y;
        count++;
      }
    }
  }

  if (count >5) {
    avgX = avgX / count;
    avgY = avgY / count;

    saveFrame("output/mov1####.png");
  }
}
```

Comment: If what you care about is the result of that work, you probably don't want to be using Processing at all here, because it's _very_ slow at pixel analysis. Using `ffmpeg` to scale down the movie to a 1x1 pixel size first should be _much_ faster, with that scaling by definition giving you the average color of the frame. Then you can load _that_ movie in Processing, instead, and now  you only have to look at single pixels and immediately have the average color information available for further work.

Comment: Try to break your problem down into smaller steps. Can you create a sketch that just plays the movie?